# PHP code refactoring

Tags: php, refactoring

what the best refactoring you will do it for this class?

i am looking here for "Extract and Combine Classes and Functions" method i think all the databases function in the coed can be combine like fetching the results and db connect and all user login.

```
<?php
$database = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user') or die('no connection');
mysql_select_db('test', $database);
session_start();

class Blog
{
    public $logged_in_users = array();

    function login()
    {
        global $database;

        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = 'no';

        $sql = "select * from user where username = '" .
            $_REQUEST['user'] . "' and password  = '" . $_REQUEST['password'] . "'";

        $result = mysql_query($sql, $database);

        if (!$result) {
            $log = fopen('Log/error.log', 'a+');
            fwrite($log, 'error while reading/writing log file');
            fclose($log);
            echo 'error while reading/writing log file';
            return;
        }

        while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
            $this->logged_in_users[] = $_REQUEST['user'];
            $_SESSION['loggedin'] = 'yes';
            $_SESSION['permission'] = $row[3];
            $_SESSION['readonly'] = $row[4];
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row[0];
        }
    }

    function insertBlog()
    {
        global $database;

        if ($_SESSION['loggedin'] == 'yes' && ($_SESSION['permission'] == 'admin' ||
            $_SESSION['permission'] == 'superuser' ||
            ( $_SESSION['permission'] == 'normal' && $_SESSION['readonly'] == 'no'))) {
            $sql = "insert into blog (text,userid) values('".$_REQUEST['text']."','" . $_SESSION['user_id'] . "')";

            $result = mysql_query($sql, $database);

            if (!$result) {
                $log = fopen('Log/error.log', 'a+');
                fwrite($log, 'error while writing new blog');
                fclose($log);
                echo 'error while writing new blog';
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    function loadBlog()
    {
        global $database;

        $sql = 'select * from blog';

        $result = mysql_query($sql, $database);

        if (!$result) {
            $log = fopen('Log/error.log', 'a+');
            fwrite($log, 'error while reading');
            fclose($log);
            echo 'error while reading';
            return;
        }

        echo "<br><table>";

        while($row =  mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {

            $sql = "select username from user where userid = " . $row[2];

            echo "<tr>";

            $result2 = mysql_query($sql, $database);

            if (!$result2) {
                $log = fopen('Log/error.log', 'a+');
                fwrite($log, 'error while reading');
                fclose($log);
                echo 'error while reading';
                return;
            }

            $row2 = mysql_fetch_row($result2);
            echo "<td>Autor : " . $row2[0]."</td>";
            echo "</tr><tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row[1] . "</td>";

            echo "</tr>";
        }

        echo "</table>";
    }

    function deleteBlog()
    {
        global $database;

        if ($_SESSION['loggedin'] == 'yes' && $_SESSION['permission'] == 'admin') {

            $sql = 'delete from blog where id = ' . $_REQUEST['id'];

            $result = mysql_query($sql, $database);

            if (!$result) {
                $log = fopen('Log/error.log', 'a+');
                fwrite($log, 'error while deleting');
                fclose($log);
                echo 'error while deleting';
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    function newUser()
    {
        global $database;

        if ($_SESSION['loggedin'] == 'yes' && $_SESSION['permission'] == 'admin') {
            $sql = "insert into user(username, password, permission, readonly) values("
            . "'{$_REQUEST['username']}', '{$_REQUEST['password']}', '{$_REQUEST['permission']}', '{$_REQUEST['readonly']}')";

            $result = mysql_query($sql, $database);
            if (!$result) {
                $log = fopen('Log/error.log', 'a+');
                fwrite($log, 'error while writing new user');
                fclose($log);
                echo 'error while writing new user';
                return;
            }
        }
    }


    function countBlogs()
    {
        global $database;

        $result = mysql_query('select count(*) as anzahl from blog', $database);

        if (!$result) {
            $log = fopen('Log/error.log', 'a+');
            fwrite($log, 'error while writing new user');
            fclose($log);
            echo 'error while counting';
            return;
        }

        $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

        echo "anzahl blogs : " . $row[0];
    }
}



$blog = new Blog();


if ($_REQUEST['action'] == 'list') {
    $blog->countBlogs();
    $blog->loadBlog();
} elseif($_REQUEST['action'] == 'new') {
    $blog->insertBlog();
    $blog->countBlogs();
    $blog->loadBlog();
} elseif($_REQUEST['action'] == 'delete') {
    $blog->deleteBlog();
    $blog->countBlogs();
    $blog->loadBlog();
} elseif($_REQUEST['action'] == 'new_user') {
    $blog->newUser();
    $blog->countBlogs();
    $blog->loadBlog();
} elseif($_REQUEST['action'] == 'login') {
    $blog->login();
    $blog->countBlogs();
    $blog->loadBlog();
} else {
    $blog->countBlogs();
    $blog->loadBlog();
}



/*
 CREATE TABLE `user` (
    `userid` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
    `username` VARCHAR( 45 ) NOT NULL ,
    `password` VARCHAR( 45 ) NOT NULL ,
    `permission` VARCHAR( 45 ) NOT NULL ,
    `readonly` VARCHAR( 45 ) NOT NULL
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `blog` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
    `text` TEXT NOT NULL ,
    `userid` INT NOT NULL
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

--liste
http://domain/blog.php

--einloggen
http://domain/blog.php?action=login&user=admin&password=admin

--neuer eintrag
http://domain/blog.php?action=new&text=bla

--neuer user
http://domain/blog.php?action=new_user&username=test&password=test&permission=superuser&readonly=yes

--eintrag löschen
http://domain/blog.php?action=delete&id=1

 */
```

Comment: Hi there, [so] doesn't really allow these types of posts because they don't really ask a programming question - rather you're asking someone here do simply do the refactoring for you.

Comment: I think this question fits better into this site: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ (@Lix Yeah it's a very open/unspecific question and I think it's on the very edge between SO and codereview, But I think it's more a codereview question)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I think this fits better into: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ and you will have a higher change to get an answer there

Comment: If this code is live you should remedy your injection issues asap. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: @Rizier123 Being on-topic at another Stack Exchange network location does not make a question off-topic on [so] or any other Stack Exchange network site.  If you feel this question is off-topic for [so], you should find a [so] defined reason (via [so]'s help center) for closing it.  Nothing in [so]'s help center says "Questions found to be on topic at [codereview.se] should be closed as off-topic here."

Comment: Now you've edited your question to something completely different? STOP causing other people to waste their time! If you want our help, you are not going about it the right way. We are not her to give you our free time as and how you feel fit. Please read the help center about what is and what isn't allowed. Asking for tools is also not allowed. This site has rules, just like any other, please do adhere to them, or you will find you end up with a suspension for not doing so. Regards...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wow, there's so much you can refactor here it's almost a crime :)

I'll suggest you some reading on [single-responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)
But you can start from the basic stuff.

1. use MVC design pattern to separate your business logic from the views and the actions
2. use singleton to connect with your DB
3. you can extract here at least 5 different classes with different resposibilities.

you just need to have some reading.
best of luck.

Comment: thanks you, it's not my code but can you please give me some example to refactoring 2 function here?

Comment: You know by answering off topic and terrible questions by users who can't be bothered to do some reading/searching of their own, you are attracting more of the same kind of question, and telling the author of this one it's ok to do so? I know you're only trying to help, I enjoy helping others, but we need to stop "feeding" lazy and terrible questions like this one! To further prove my point, **your answer is now invalid** because the author has changed from asking how to refactor the code they posted, to asking what is the best refactoring tools. A waste of your time...

Comment: Absolutely right the answer is *absolutely wrong* but you are leaving it there anyway?

Comment: you think I should delete it?

Comment: up to you. It answers the old question, not the new one (it was wrong for dev.bashar to edit in such a way it changed the entire scope of the question). This Q will be closed soon anyway, so probs not matter either way..